# How to eliminate static-y hair?

Tags: personal-care, hair

During the winter my hair gets static-y and starts to stick straight out.  How can I combat/prevent this from happening?
I would like something that would work while I am away from home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My wife runs dryer sheets through her hair for that.  She says they work great.

Comment: Any brand work better than others, or does that not seem to matter?

Comment: We just use the generic Wal-Mart brand.  She runs them through her hair.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've accepted the answer, but preventing this problem is the sole reason I use fabric conditioner on laundry, otherwise, not only is my hair doing strange things, but my clothes are likely to stick to each other while I'm wearing them, and spark and crackle when I take them off... and fabric conditioner is what's in dryer sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You should try hair oil.

> 3. Seal the Moisture
>      If your hair is of medium density or a wavy texture, an oil based leave-in conditioner is a better option. Apply an even coat after towel drying. This helps to seal moisture into your hair before the dry air around you has a chance to rob moisture away. Again, you don’t need a market bought conditioner. Jojoba oil, or coconut oil, or peach kernel oil or shea butter will make a wonderful leave-in conditioner. Rub a small amount into your palms then spread it through your hair. It will give you a great boost of sheen and volume and prevent further flyaway. Obviously, use sparingly and keep away from your roots and fringe.   http://www.hairbuddha.net/prevent-static-hair/